# How to use Aspose.Cells in existing project in netBeans?

Tags: java, excel, image-conversion, aspose-cells, netbeans-8.2

I want to convert excel sheet data to image and currently I was working with graphics 2D of awt but it is not giving me desired result. I have read that aspose.cells can be used for converting to image but when I try to implement it gives me error like this-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.font.FontManager.getFontPath(Z)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.aspose.cells.a.c.cf.p(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.a.c.cf.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.eY.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.vm.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.SheetRender.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.boolment.dataentry.ExcelTesting.generateImages(ExcelTesting.java:28)
    at com.boolment.dataentry.ExcelTesting.main(ExcelTesting.java:16)
```

The code I have written for converting file is-

```
package com.boolment.dataentry;

import com.aspose.cells.ImageFormat;
import com.aspose.cells.ImageOrPrintOptions;
import com.aspose.cells.SheetRender;
import com.aspose.cells.Workbook;
import com.aspose.cells.Worksheet;
import com.aspose.cells.WorksheetCollection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExcelTesting {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception{
        ExcelTesting et = new ExcelTesting();       
        String sourcePath = "C:\\Users\\TANISHA AGARWAL\\Downloads\\EXCEL FORMAT.xls";
        et.generateImages(sourcePath);
    }

    public void generateImages(final String sourcePath) {  
     try {  
         Workbook workbook = new Workbook(sourcePath);  
         List<Worksheet> worksheets = getAllWorksheets(workbook);  
         if (worksheets != null) {  
             int noOfImages = 0;  
             for (Worksheet worksheet : worksheets) {  
                 if (worksheet.getCells().getCount() > 0 || worksheet.getCharts().getCount() > 0 || worksheet.getPictures().getCount() > 0) {  
                     String imageFilePath = sourcePath + "_output_" + (noOfImages++) + ".jpeg";   
                     SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(worksheet, getImageOrPrintOptions());  
                     sr.toImage(0, imageFilePath);  
                 }  
             }  
         }  
     } catch (Exception e) {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
     }  
 }  
    private List<Worksheet> getAllWorksheets(final Workbook workbook) {  
     List<Worksheet> worksheets = new ArrayList<Worksheet>();  
     WorksheetCollection worksheetCollection = workbook.getWorksheets();  
     for (int i = 0; i < worksheetCollection.getCount(); i++) {  
         worksheets.add(worksheetCollection.get(i));  
     }  
     return worksheets;  
 }  
    private ImageOrPrintOptions getImageOrPrintOptions() {  
     ImageOrPrintOptions imgOptions = new ImageOrPrintOptions();  
     imgOptions.setImageFormat(ImageFormat.getJpeg());  
     imgOptions.setOnePagePerSheet(true);  
     return imgOptions;  
 }  
}
```

I have include aspose.cells 7.0 jar but still its not working...Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the JDK version you are using?

Comment: I an using JDK 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspose Cells for Java 7.0 is quite outdated. There is currently version 18.7. Might be that version 7.0 is not compatible with your JDK version. Please try to use the newest version of Aspose Cells and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: How can I download it?

Comment: so, you got it right now. In the newer versions (you may get by navigating to Aspose site), we have added more enhancements and fixes regarding rendering sheet to image feature. Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.